# Drain a 3V coin battery with Labview to test the lifetime of the battery?

Tags: measurement, labview

I want to simulate/measure the lifetime of a 3V coin battery. This is the circuit which will give the burst to the battery:

[link text](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/8206/schematicpicturev2.png)

The burst is controlled with the CTRL1 and CTRL2 lines with some timing rquirements.

One burst is:

```
                ARM    TX   RX     TX      RX   TX
CTRL1           L      H    H      H       H    H
CTRL2           H      H    L      H       L    H
Length (ms)     3.72   2.6  0.84   4.04    0.8  1

H = 10 V
L = 0 V
```

Now I want to drain the battery by applying one Burst gap one Burst gap etc..
The gap should be variable. First I want to use 10 seconds as a gap. I want to draw the battery characteristic. I wanna simulate for example 5 years which should be 1.2 days in the simulation. I have the NI PCI 6221 (37 pin) DAQ card. Can somebody help me to make a VI for this project. The bursts should be in a loop which I should be able to control how long it should run (i.e. 1 day, or 1.5 days) And how I can apply 10 V or 0 V to the CTRL1 and CTRL2 lines in Labview?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Ok I have now made a continously acquiring voltage and graphing VI which has a physical channel as an input from where the voltage is acquired. But I dont know how to do the counters part which will output the timed signals for the TTL (MOSFET) to create the burst signal with gaps which then will drain the batterry.

Comment: Just edited my answer before I saw your edit. You probably want to use actual time delays, so look under Programming > Timing for the Wait (ms) VI.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the DAQ Assistant. Look for tutorials that include this VI.
On the block diagram look under Measurement I/O > DAQmx - Data Acquisition > DAQ Assistant. You should be able to hook that up to your DAQ card.

Look at [NI Forums](http://forums.ni.com/) too.

**EDIT:** If you're unfamiliar with or new to LabVIEW, just browse the example code located in National Instruments\LabVIEW x.x\examples. For your applications, examples\DAQmx would probably have relevant code. Stick to basics at first, such as examples\general. You can even modify the examples just don't overwrite by accident.

Comment: I know about the Assistant but I do not know how to do the logic configuration and timing for the burst signal. How to drive the CTRL1 and CTRL2 to get the ARM, TX, and RX